# Calculating problem: dual values with CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

I modeled a linear problem for test purposes in CPLEX using its own script language. So long, everything works fine, except that three dual values are wrongly calculated.

In particular sigma_2, sigma_4 and sigma_7 are wrong. According to the solution of the book where I got the problem from, the values should be as written down below.

Conspicuously, all of the wrongly calculated values are smaller than those in the sample solution.

Many thanks for any help in advance. Would be really thankful for any helping hint.

While defining the constraints, I assign a label:

```
forall (k in 1..numberOfProducts)
  constraintII: // label for the constraint
  sum (n in 1..N[numberOfProducts]) delta [k,n]== 1;
```

I obtain the dual values by adressing them via labels:

```
for(w=1; w<=numberOfProducts; w++) {
    writeln("dual value sigma_",w," = ",constraintII[w].dual);
}
```

expected results:

```
sigma_2 = 1000
sigma_4 = 1000
sigma_7 = 1000
```

actual results:

```
sigma_2 = 789,93
sigma_4 = 112,81
sigma_7 = 160,29
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is not an alternate optimal solution? Have you tried using the expected solution as a warmstart (for an example see opl/examples/opl/warmstart/warmstart.mod)?

Comment: Did you check that the solution is actually incorrect? Are the values incorrect for the dual problem? Do these dual values give a different objective value? Like Ryan said, (dual) solutions need not be unique. If the dual solution indeed turns out to be incorrect then you should show your full model and data so that people can reproduce.